# Configure WordPress to have distinct backgrounds for blog posts

Tags: css, wordpress

What is the proper way to set all blog posts to have a certain background in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this depends on the theme but you can achieve this in your CSS. Check to see that your blog posts are adding a particular class to the `body` tag and then do something like this in your theme's CSS file:

```css
.single-post, .single, .post { background-color: #ff9900; }
```

That above CSS sets the background color of the page to a certain color, but it only applies to pages that have that CSS class present. I would check your active theme and also refer to the [documentation on post classes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) to be on the safe side.